# Prevent applying shopping cart rule for specific customer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, shopping-cart-price-rules

Is it possible to prevent applying shopping cart price rule, for the specific customer, of the using event observer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use event "salesrule_validator_process" to validate your condition